# Different results of t test and biserial correlation?

Tags: r, correlation, t-test, group-differences, pearson-r

I was wondering whether it is possible that a t test and a point biserial correlation can give different results (t-test shows groups differ significantly, correlation implies that variable does not increase/decrease by group).
If yes, why is that?